# Outlook.attachment refuses to load my image

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to add an image attachment to my C# application that will send when I send an email through outllook. The only time it will recognice the image is if I include the full file path. I have tried linking it through resources as well as changing the CopyToOutputDirectory property of the file and then including it like I did with my html file, `@".\Web\index.htm"`elsewhere in the project but that does not work either.

The code that works

```
Outlook.Attachment attachment = mailItem.Attachments.Add(
     @"C:\Testing\ConsoleApplication\ConsoleApplication\Web\MCGLogo.jpg"
                           , Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem
                           , null
                           , "Montgomery, Coscia, Greilich"
                           );
```

Answer (score 0):

olEmbeddeditem means an embedded message attachment. 
In your case, an image is just a regular olByValue type attachment. You can only add file attachments, resources or link won't work. You must save the attachment as a file fist.

Is this an HTML image? Did you make sure the image is referenced by the HTML body through the cid attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the image to the item and then using the HTMLBody to write HTML to add the attachment **cid** as a reference in the HTML. For example:

```
 Attachment attachment = mailItem.Attachments.Add(
    "C://test.bmp"
    , OlAttachmentType.olByValue
    , null
    , "test image"
    );
    string imageCid = "test.bmp@123";

    attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"
        , imageCid
        );
    mailItem.HTMLBody = String.Format(
          "<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\"></body>"
         , imageCid);
    mailItem.Display(false);
```